# How to LEFT JOIN three tables with order by?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have tried many times but every time its getting sql syntax error so i splited it into two queries but i want it to be one.Please help me.Follwing is the code:

```
$pictures = $db->get_results(sprintf("SELECT imageID, image_name, image_date, username, userID 
            FROM images LEFT JOIN users ON images.image_user = users.userID 
            WHERE show_in_gallery = 'Y' AND image_user = '%d' 
            ORDER BY imageID DESC LIMIT 0, 24", $data['userID']));
$stats = $db->get_results(sprintf("SELECT STAT.imageID, STAT.image_views,STAT.unique_views,STAT.earnings 
        FROM image_stats as STAT LEFT JOIN images as IMG ON STAT.imageID = IMG.imageID 
        WHERE  image_user = '%d' 
        ORDER BY imageID DESC LIMIT 0, 24", $data['userID']));
```

And here is the error:

> Warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'is ON is.imageID = i.imageID WHERE show_in_gallery= 'Y' AND
>   image_user = '8' ORD' at line 1

Comment: Can you provide the one query you tried and that shows you syntax error ?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: <code>$pictures = $db->get_results(sprintf("SELECT i.imageID, i.image_name, i.image_date, i.username, i.userID FROM images as i LEFT JOIN users as u ON i.image_user = u.userID LEFT JOIN image_stats as is ON is.imageID = i.imageID WHERE show_in_gallery= 'Y' AND image_user = '%d' ORDER BY imageID DESC LIMIT 0, 24", $data['userID']));</code>

Comment: This gives following error:Warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'is ON is.imageID = i.imageID WHERE show_in_gallery= 'Y' AND image_user = '8' ORD' at line 1 in

Comment: You are getting syntax error is because `IS` is predefined in Mysql you can use another word instead of `IS` and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you want? Not entirely sure why your attempt failed.

```
SELECT IMG.imageID, IMG.image_name, IMG.image_date,
    USR.username, USR.userID,
    STAT.image_views, STAT.unique_views, STAT.earnings 
FROM image_stats as STAT LEFT JOIN images as IMG 
    ON STAT.imageID = IMG.imageID
LEFT JOIN users as USR 
    ON IMG.image_user = USR.userID
WHERE  image_user = '%d' AND USR.show_in_gallery = 'Y'
ORDER BY imageID DESC LIMIT 0, 24
```